# Как средствами css или jquery выбрать элементы по началу имени атрибута для задания стиля?

Tags: jquery, css

Как объединить в общий стиль именно по наличию атрибута `attr-v*`?

```
.myclass[attr-v1], .myclass[attr-v2], .myclass[attr-v3] {
    ...
}

<div attr-v1 class="myclass">...
<div attr-v2 class="myclass">...
<div attr-v1 class="myclass">...
```

По началу значения атрибута следующим образом: `[attr^="значение"]`, а как по началу имени атрибута сделать выборку?

Update: если средствами `css` невозможно это реализовать, возможно ли средствами `javascript/jquery` задать стиль? Если да, то как, если эти атрибуты добавляются динамически?

Comment: [Есть селекторы, для элементов, которые имеют класс, начинающийся с некоторого префикса](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). А вот для атрибутов непонятно — в html ведь имена атрибутов не могут быть произвольными (то есть html невалидным получается)?

Comment: Никак нельзя это сделать (пока что). В [стандарте показаны](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) все способы манипуляции с селекторами атрибутов. Того, чего хотите вы, там, к сожалению, нет.

Answer (score 1):

То, как вы хотите реализовать динамическое добавление атрибутов и стилизацию по ним — это неправильное желание. Если блоки семантически объединены (иначе зачем их еще одинаково стилизовать), то им следует задать одно имя атрибута и менять его значения. Тогда и подходящий селектор для этого можно будет использовать. Например, так:

```css
div[data-attr^="v"] {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div data-attr="v1"></div>
<div data-attr="v2"></div>
<div data-attr="v3"></div>
<div data-attr="v4"></div>
```